# Setting up subdomain - AWS & Laravel

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, amazon-web-services, laravel-5

I'm slowly migrating my website into the artisan era using Laravel.
I have it setup on `AWS` on a vanilla Amazon linux.

Currently I have;
`www.example.co.uk`
`blog.example.co.uk`
`careers.example.co.uk`

These are all on the same server and the subdomains have been achieved using `htaccess` to redirect to `\blog` and `\careers` folders in my `root` with `DNS` being handled by `Route 53`

Now in moving to `laravel` it only considers the `public` folder (`htaccess` use no longer required apart from the default one it comes with) so I have my `DocumentRoot` as `/var/www/example/public`. Everything works great! Setup a bunch of `routes` for my main site and still smooth sailing.

Now moving to the subdomains, I have the below in my `hhtpd.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName blog.example.co.uk
  ServerAdmin webmaster@blog.example.co.uk

  DocumentRoot /var/www/example/public

  <Directory /var/www/example/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog /var/log/blog.example.co.uk.error.log
  LogLevel warn
  CustomLog /var/log/blog.example.co.uk.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

As you can see I'm pointing the subdomain to the same public folder since `Laravel` should be able to see that `blog.example.co.uk` was requested and perform its duties to route correctly.

I have the below routes for the subdomain

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'blog.example.co.uk'], function () {

    Route::get('/', 'BlogController@home')->name('blog-home');
    Route::get('review', 'BlogController@review')->name('blog-review');
    Route::get('author/{id}', 'BlogController@author')->name('blog-author')->middleware('blogGuard');
    Route::get('category/{id}', 'BlogController@category')->name('blog-category')->middleware('blogGuard');
    Route::get('post/{id}', 'BlogController@post')->name('blog-post')->middleware('blogGuard');
    Route::get('press', 'BlogController@press')->name('blog-press');
    Route::get('about', 'BlogController@about')->name('blog-about');

});
```

Unfortunately, going to `blog.example.co.uk` still assumes that I requested `www.example.co.uk` and routes using the logic for the main site. So `blog.example` points to `www.example`.

I have also used `'{blog}.example.co.uk'`

What am I doing wrong please
Cheers!

Comment: Are all of your routes divided up into domain groups? If not, it's possible there is some order of operations going on with your routes where it matches a route before it even reaches the subdomain route group. I'd suggest either putting everything into its own route group or making sure your non-grouped routes are below your grouped routes and see if that does the trick.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks! Divided them into groups and now works. Feel free to leave an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Glad to hear it! I went ahead and made it an answer if you wouldn't mind accepting :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is an issue with the order of operations of your routes, where it matches a route before it even reaches the subdomain route group. You should put everything into its own route group and that should solve the problem. As an alternative you could make sure your non-grouped routes are below your grouped routes and that might also solve the problem.